# Activerecord 3.2.8 associations error

Tags: ruby, multithreading, activerecord

I'm encountering strange error with ActiveRecord 3.2.8 with this code:

I have 2 models - Customer and Invoice.

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :invoices
end

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer

  def self.last(customer)
    customer.invoices.order("some_date_column DESC").first
  end
end
```

I'm running a code similar to this:

```
Thread.new do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do
    Customer.all.each do |customer|
      invoice = Invoice.last(customer)
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

When running that code I sometimes get the following strange error:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:25:in 'initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) (ArgumentError)
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:25:in 'new'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:25:in 'initialize'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations.rb:157:in 'new'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations.rb:157:in 'association'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:44:in 'invoices'
from .../models/invoice.rb:7:in 'last'
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you get this kind of error

```
wrong number of arguments (X for Y)
```

It means you tried to invoke a method passing a different number of arguments than it expected. In your case the method you invoked wasn't supposed to receive any arguments (`for 0`), but you tried to pass one (`1 for`). From the last line in the error, it seems the problem is `Invoice.last(customer)`

Comment: Thanks but as you can see in the method definition, the Invoice.last method is supposed to accept exactly 1 argument. The ArgumentError got raised in ActiveRecords's collection_association.rb file on line 25 when calling method new.